# How to use Help Token in RpcException in GCP?

Tags: exception, google-cloud-platform, rpc

I'm trying to enable some API and getting this exception -

Permission denied to enable service [sqladmin.googleapis.com] Help Token: `The token comes here`

I can't find how to use this token to try and troubleshoot the problem or get any extra information about the error.
Tried searching where to put the Help Token but can't find any field or troubleshooting form to work with.

(I know that I need to add permission to enable APIs, it's just an example to error that contains Help Token)

Comment: Your question would benefit from more detail. How are you trying to enable this API? Are you using `gcloud services enable sqladmin.googleapis.com`? It's likely that your account does not have the correct permissions to enable services. See [Access Control with IAM](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/access-control). You need a role that includes `services.enable`

Comment: @DazWilkin his question is not about how to enable a service, as he mentioned, that that's only an example. On other permission Errors one would receive a http response that also contains "Help  Token: [some_long_token] " in the http response. The Question is: how does one use this Help token?

Comment: IIRC the token is only for Google's internal use to investigate a technical issue. Open a support case and provide the token to support.